# Wordpress custom posts won`t be displayed under the archive-{postname}.php

Tags: php, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom post called forums. I`m trying to list all the posts under forums on archives-forums.php but everything under the while loop is not visible. Below is my sample code:

**archive-forums.php**

```
get_header(); ?>

<div class="page-banner">
  <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/ocean.jpg') ?>);"></div>
  <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
    <h1 class="page-banner__title">Forums</h1>
    <div class="page-banner__intro">
      <p>There is something for everyone. Have a look around.</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="container container--narrow page-section">

<ul class="link-list min-list">

<?php
  while(have_posts()) {
    the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
  <?php }
  echo paginate_links();
?>
</ul>
</div>

<?php get_footer();

?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function test_adjust_queries($query) {

        if (!is_admin() AND is_post_type_archive('forum') AND $query->is_main_query()) {
            $query->set('orderby', 'title');
            $query->set('order', 'ASC');
            $query->set('posts_per_page', -1);
          }

        if (!is_admin() AND is_post_type_archive() AND $query->is_main_query()) {

            $today = date('Ymd');

            $query->set('meta_key', 'event_date');
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
            $query->set('order', 'ASC');
            $query->set('meta_query', array (
              array (
                'key' => 'event_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => $today,
                'type' => ' numeric'
              )
            ));


        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'test_adjust_queries');
```

Comment: "but everything under the while loop is not visible" - could you provide more details?

Comment: When you view the page the posts are not displayed